# Get data with boundaries using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I would like to get the labels and data from this function using regex, I have tried using this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'/blabels: ],/b')
print(pattern)
result = soup.find("script", text=pattern)
```

But I get None using boundaries

This is the `soup`:

```
<script>
Chart.defaults.LineWithLine = Chart.defaults.line;

new Chart(document.getElementById("chart-overall-mentions"), {
  type: 'LineWithLine',
  data: {
    labels: [1637005508000,1637006108000,1637006708000,1637007308000,1637007908000,1637008508000,1637009108000,1637009708000,1637010308000,1637010908000,1637011508000,1637012108000,1637012708000,1637013308000,1637013908000,1637014508000,1637015108000,1637015708000,1637016308000,1637016908000,1637017508000,1637018108000,1637018708000,1637019308000,1637019908000,1637020508000,1637021108000,1637021708000,1637022308000,1637022908000,1637023508000,1637024108000,1637024708000,1637025308000,1637025908000,1637026508000,1637027108000,1637027708000,1637028308000,1637028908000,1637029508000,1637030108000,1637030708000,1637031308000,1637031908000,1637032508000,1637033108000,1637033708000,1637034308000,1637034908000,1637035508000,1637036108000,1637036708000,1637037308000,1637037908000,1637038508000,1637039108000,1637039708000,1637040308000,1637040908000,1637041508000,1637042108000,1637042708000,1637043308000,1637043908000,1637044508000,1637045108000,1637045708000,1637046308000,1637046908000,1637047508000,1637048108000,1637048708000,1637049308000,1637049908000,1637050508000,1637051108000,1637051708000,1637052308000,1637052908000,1637053508000,1637054108000,1637054708000,1637055308000,1637055908000,1637056508000,1637057108000,1637057708000,1637058308000,1637058908000,1637059508000,1637060108000,1637060708000,1637061308000,1637061908000,1637062508000,1637063108000,1637063708000,1637064308000,1637064908000,1637065508000,1637066108000,1637066708000,1637067308000,1637067908000,1637068508000,1637069108000,1637069708000,1637070308000,1637070908000,1637071508000,1637072108000,1637072708000,1637073308000,1637073908000,1637074508000,1637075108000,1637075708000,1637076308000,1637076908000,1637077508000,1637078108000,1637078708000,1637079308000,1637079908000,1637080508000,1637081108000,1637081708000,1637082308000,1637082908000,1637083508000,1637084108000,1637084708000,1637085308000,1637085908000,1637086508000,1637087108000,1637087708000,1637088308000,1637088908000,1637089508000,1637090108000,1637090708000,1637091308000],
    datasets: [{
        data: [13,10,20,26,21,23,24,21,24,35,25,31,42,24,24,20,23,22,17,23,30,11,16,20,9,10,22,10,19,16,15,16,17,19,10,20,24,14,19,15,13,9,13,17,20,16,15,21,18,25,15,14,16,15,16,14,14,21,10,9,5,9,9,13,14,9,9,18,15,11,11,6,12,14,19,17,16,11,20,14,21,13,15,12,14,10,20,16,25,17,17,11,23,11,13,11,19,10,17,19,10,20,22,19,19,27,28,18,20,22,18,16,17,18,14,17,19,18,20,11,13,20,15,15,18,14,13,14,14,11,19,14,14,11,11,15,26,12,15,15,11,4,3,6],
        pointRadius: 0,
        borderColor: "#666",
        fill: true,
        yAxisID:'yAxis1'
      },
    ]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      bodyFontSize: 18,
      intersect: false,
      titleFontSize: 16,
    },
.
.
.
</script>
```

Comment: Word boundary syntax is `\b`. Also, `,\b` will only match if there is a word char after `,`

Comment: Do you want to find the script tag, or extract all the numbers from `labels` field?

Comment: I want the values, I thought this expression (r'\blabels: ],\b) would return the data that starts with labels: and end with ],

Comment: No, the code and the expression are not doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do that:

- Get the script tag - you can use a regex, too, if that is the only way to obtain that node
- Then run a regex search against the node text/string to get your final output.

You can use

```py
# Get the script node with text matching your pattern
item = soup.find("script", text=re.compile(r'\blabels:\s*\['))

import re
match = re.search(r'\blabels:\s*\[([^][]*)]', item.string)
if match:
    labels = map(int, match.group(1).split(','))
```

Output:

```
>>> print(list(labels))
[1637005508000, 1637006108000, 1637006708000, 1637007308000, 1637007908000, 1637008508000, 1637009108000, 1637009708000, 1637010308000, 1637010908000, 1637011508000, 1637012108000, 1637012708000, 1637013308000, 1637013908000, 1637014508000, 1637015108000, 1637015708000, 1637016308000, 1637016908000, 1637017508000, 1637018108000, 1637018708000, 1637019308000, 1637019908000, 1637020508000, 1637021108000, 1637021708000, 1637022308000, 1637022908000, 1637023508000, 1637024108000, 1637024708000, 1637025308000, 1637025908000, 1637026508000, 1637027108000, 1637027708000, 1637028308000, 1637028908000, 1637029508000, 1637030108000, 1637030708000, 1637031308000, 1637031908000, 1637032508000, 1637033108000, 1637033708000, 1637034308000, 1637034908000, 1637035508000, 1637036108000, 1637036708000, 1637037308000, 1637037908000, 1637038508000, 1637039108000, 1637039708000, 1637040308000, 1637040908000, 1637041508000, 1637042108000, 1637042708000, 1637043308000, 1637043908000, 1637044508000, 1637045108000, 1637045708000, 1637046308000, 1637046908000, 1637047508000, 1637048108000, 1637048708000, 1637049308000, 1637049908000, 1637050508000, 1637051108000, 1637051708000, 1637052308000, 1637052908000, 1637053508000, 1637054108000, 1637054708000, 1637055308000, 1637055908000, 1637056508000, 1637057108000, 1637057708000, 1637058308000, 1637058908000, 1637059508000, 1637060108000, 1637060708000, 1637061308000, 1637061908000, 1637062508000, 1637063108000, 1637063708000, 1637064308000, 1637064908000, 1637065508000, 1637066108000, 1637066708000, 1637067308000, 1637067908000, 1637068508000, 1637069108000, 1637069708000, 1637070308000, 1637070908000, 1637071508000, 1637072108000, 1637072708000, 1637073308000, 1637073908000, 1637074508000, 1637075108000, 1637075708000, 1637076308000, 1637076908000, 1637077508000, 1637078108000, 1637078708000, 1637079308000, 1637079908000, 1637080508000, 1637081108000, 1637081708000, 1637082308000, 1637082908000, 1637083508000, 1637084108000, 1637084708000, 1637085308000, 1637085908000, 1637086508000, 1637087108000, 1637087708000, 1637088308000, 1637088908000, 1637089508000, 1637090108000, 1637090708000, 1637091308000]
```

Once the node is obtained the `\blabels:\s*\[([^][]*)]` regex searches for

- `\b`  - a word boundary
- `labels:` - a fixed string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^][]*)` - Group 1 (this is what you will need to split with a comma later): any zero or more chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]` - a `]` char.